# How to set the value of Match into a Range for vlookup

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to perform a vlookup using vba. On the code the only thing I'm missing how to store the result of match into range to use it

```
Sub pn_relationships2()

Dim pn As Range
Dim Rng As Range
Dim Col As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("Entities")
        
    Worksheets("Relationships").Activate

Set Rng = Range("D:K")

    Worksheets("Entities").Activate
    Cells.Find(What:="Part Number", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas2, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

Set pn = ActiveCell

Match_Value = WorksheetFunction.Match("Part Number", ws.Range("D2:K2"), 0)

Set Col = WorksheetFunction.Match("Part Number", ws.Range("D2:K2"), 0)
```

Most likely the last 2 lines are wrong.

Comment: Match returns a number (or an error if no match)  - you can't assign that to a range variable like `Col`.  Would help to describe what happens when you run your code.  You seem to be doing a few different but similar things in your code, so it would help to say what it's supposed to be doing.

Comment: @TimWilliams Pretty much trying to run a vlookup function, the "Col" It's supposed to be the col_index_num

Comment: @TimWilliams That was my goal. `Range("P3") = Application.VLookup(C3, Rng, Col, True)`

Answer (score 0):

Like this maybe:

```vb
  Sub pn_relationships2()
    
        Dim ws As Worksheet, m, Rng As Range
        
        Set ws = Sheets("Entities")
        Set Rng = ws.Range("D:K")
        'find the part number header position
        m = Application.Match("Part Number", Rng.Rows(2), 0)
        
        If Not IsError(m) Then
            Debug.Print Application.VLookup(someValue, Rng, m, True)
        Else
            MsgBox "'Part Number' header not found"
        End If
                
    End Sub
```